# Messing up with a calculator using a GridLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm facing troubles with making layouts look nice.

To understand basics, I've decided to create a simple calculator app.
So, I'm using a GridLayout nested in a LinearLayout to place Buttons under text fields.

Here is the source of my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_weight="30"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:useDefaultMargins="false"
        android:layout_weight="70">

        <Button
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:text="BS" />

        <Button
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:text="x" />

        <Button
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:text="=" />
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:text="0" />
        <Button
            android:text="." />
    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to make this layout fill the screen?

[image: current app]

And make my app looking like this

[image: want to look like]

Hoping for quick answers.

[EDIT]: So, now things are way better, but I got new questions.
Now my main activity looks like this

[image: this]

Quite nice, in my opinion, but:

1. How to remove empty space on the right side of keyboard?
2. How to make keyboard and text view taking like 70 and 30 percents of screen respectively?

Also, new layout code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="android.calcandroid.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:useDefaultMargins="false">

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="BS" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="x" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:text="=" />
        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:text="0" />
        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:text="." />
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try using a TableLayout. Then you can stretch the columns to fit the width of the screen

Comment: And grid couldn't do it?

Comment: A GridView or a GridLayout would be just perfect, for a calculator app.

Comment: @Rotwang So, can you please tell me, what's I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It actually depends on your expectations on `making layout looking nice`

Comment: @Rotwang
I trying to make something that will look like xiaomi calc: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VRBIX.jpg

Comment: Fine. Perfect for a GridLayout, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got pretty close. Not sure how to handle the vertical dividers. For some reason putting a `1dp` View between each column that spanned each row causes the GridLayout to expand the entire View.

And to use this, you need this dependency for your support library version

```
compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:<support library number>"
```

[image: emulator]

color.xml

```
<color name="calcAccent">#ef6c00</color>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="calcAction">
    <item name="android:background">#f7f8fa</item>
</style>
<style name="calcNumber">
    <item name="android:background">#fafbfd</item>
</style>
```

Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:singleLine="true" android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textSize="48sp" android:background="#e3e7ea" android:paddingBottom="32dp"
            android:padding="16dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            grid:useDefaultMargins="false" grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds" grid:columnCount="7" grid:rowCount="9">

        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <Button
                android:text="C"
                grid:layout_row="0" grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcAction" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@color/calcAccent"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
                grid:layout_row="0" grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />
        <Button
                android:text="&#247;"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1" grid:layout_column="4"/>
        <Button
                android:text="x"
                grid:layout_row="0" grid:layout_column="6"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcAction"/>

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="1" grid:layout_column="0" grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>
        <Button
                android:text="7" grid:layout_row="2" grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>
        <Button
                android:text="8" grid:layout_row="2" grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:text="9" grid:layout_row="2" grid:layout_column="4"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:text="-" grid:layout_row="2" grid:layout_column="6"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

        <!-- Row 3 -->
        <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="3" grid:layout_column="0" grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>
        <Button
                android:text="4" grid:layout_row="4" grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:text="5" grid:layout_row="4" grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:text="6" grid:layout_row="4" grid:layout_column="4"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:text="+" grid:layout_row="4" grid:layout_column="6"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

        <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="7" grid:layout_column="0" grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>

        <!-- Row 4 -->
        <Button
                android:text="1" grid:layout_row="6" grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:text="2" grid:layout_row="6" grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:text="3" grid:layout_row="6" grid:layout_column="4"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:text="=" grid:layout_row="6" grid:layout_column="6"
                style="@style/calcNumber" android:background="@color/calcAccent"
                grid:layout_rowSpan="3"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="22sp"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" android:padding="8dp"/>
        <!-- Row 5 -->

        <Button
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="0"
                grid:layout_row="8" grid:layout_column="0" grid:layout_columnSpan="3"
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>
        <Button
                android:text="."
                grid:layout_row="8" grid:layout_column="4"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1" style="@style/calcNumber"/>

        <!-- Horizontal Grid -->
        <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="5" grid:layout_column="0" grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wow, that's fantactic!

Comment: Yeah, I considered adding the full border around each button, but I didn't want to "double" the thickness on the edges, so I put thin view rows between the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Change your = and 0 buttons to:

```
<Button
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:text="=" />
<Button
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:text="0" />
```

[EDIT]

I realised from your comment that the = button was protruding to the bottom of the screen. This will be because you assigned a high weight to the calculator so using fill_vertical would do that.

I am *assuming* (but correct me if I'm wrong) from the desired graphic you showed that you want the calculator to be aligned to the bottom of the screen. If that's the case, here's my suggested amendment to your layout (tldr: use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gridLayout" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:rowCount="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:useDefaultMargins="false">

        <Button
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:text="BS" />

        <Button
            android:text="/" />

        <Button
            android:text="x" />

        <Button
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:text="=" />
        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:text="0" />
        <Button
            android:text="." />
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @ChrisWard.
But on emulator it's still looks quite strange:
http://imgur.com/a/AY9hO
Why?

Comment: Hi @likeanowl, I see the problem and I've made an edit to my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after almost ten hours I'm satisfied.
[Now its looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZLS5.png)

based on @cricket_007 suggestion, my code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context="android.calcandroid.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="0"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:background="#e3e7ea"
            android:paddingBottom="32dp"
            android:padding="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80">

        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            grid:useDefaultMargins="false"
            grid:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
            grid:columnCount="7"
            grid:rowCount="9">

            <!-- Row 1 -->
            <Button
                android:text="C"
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/calcAccent"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="&#247;"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                grid:layout_column="4"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="x"
                grid:layout_row="0"
                grid:layout_column="6"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcAction"/>

            <!-- Row 2 -->
            <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="1"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="7"
                grid:layout_row="2"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="8"
                grid:layout_row="2"
                grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="9"
                grid:layout_row="2"
                grid:layout_column="4"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="-"
                grid:layout_row="2"
                grid:layout_column="6"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <!-- Row 3 -->

            <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="3"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="4"
                grid:layout_row="4"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="5"
                grid:layout_row="4"
                grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="6"
                grid:layout_row="4"
                grid:layout_column="4"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="+"
                grid:layout_row="4"
                grid:layout_column="6"
                style="@style/calcAction"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="7"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>

            <!-- Row 4 -->

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="1"
                grid:layout_row="6"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:text="2"
                grid:layout_row="6"
                grid:layout_column="2"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_row="6"
                grid:layout_column="4"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:text="3"
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>

            <Button
                grid:layout_row="6"
                grid:layout_column="6"
                grid:layout_rowSpan="3"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="@color/calcAccent"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="="
                style="@style/calcNumber"/>
            <!-- Row 5 -->

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                grid:layout_row="8"
                grid:layout_column="0"
                grid:layout_columnSpan="3"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                android:text="0"/>

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                grid:layout_row="8"
                grid:layout_column="4"
                grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
                grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
                style="@style/calcNumber"
                android:text="."/>

            <!-- Horizontal Grid -->
            <View
                grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                grid:layout_row="5" grid:layout_column="0" grid:layout_columnSpan="7"
                android:background="#eee"/>


        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe it's a bit messy, but it's fine I think.