# ImageButton gets pushed out of the screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

So my layout code is something like

```
Linear layout - vertical
    Linear layout - horizontal
          ImageButton1
          ImageButton2
          ImageButton3
    /Linear Layout
    Linear layout - horizontal
          ImageButton1
          ImageButton2
          ImageButton3
    /Linear Layout
    Linear layout - horizontal
          ImageButton1
          ImageButton2
          ImageButton3
    /Linear Layout
    Linear layout - horizontal
          ImageButton1
          ImageButton2
          ImageButton3
    /Linear Layout
    Linear layout - horizontal
          ImageButton1
    /Linear Layout

/LinearLayout
```

You can imagine the layout that of a calculator.

So everything is fine but on the smallest screen, my last button get squished and you cant see it.
Now I know weightSum can be applied on horizontal layout and individual layout_weight on its elements.

But I was wondering is there any way to give weightSum to the vertical Parent layout and layout weight to the horizontal layouts, so that my last horizontal layout does not get pushed out.
I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Nested LinearLayout usually is bad. Try looking into GridLayout (which works well for a calculator)

Comment: Dang, I completely forgot about Gridlayout. Thanks. I'll try grid layout. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I answered a similar calculator question a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056480/messing-up-with-a-calculator-using-a-gridlayout/39058416#39058416