# Grid Layout android not working properly?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a calculator in android using Grid Layout and it doesn't show the fourth button as i have already make the 4 columns but its not working. Here is the image it shows in android studio how it looks

[android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG4mW.png)

Here it how looks when executed actually on device

[android 9,Api 28](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2e1p.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="5"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Clear"
        style="@style/FunctionalButtons"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:text="C"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Percentage"
        style="@style/FunctionalButtons"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="%"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Division"
        style="@style/FunctionalButtons"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="/"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Divis"
        style="@style/FunctionalButtons"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="/"
        android:visibility="visible" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Divis1"
        style="@style/FunctionalButtons"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="/"
        android:visibility="visible" />


       </GridLayout>
```

it works fine when i add three buttons. I have also tried putting it under Linear Layout as well but it still shows the same issue. Do i have to do something in the java code as well?

Comment: Post the `FunctionalButtons` content

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056480/messing-up-with-a-calculator-using-a-gridlayout